# Training caseless NER models with Stanford corenlp

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I know how to train an NER model as specified [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html) and have a very successful one in fact. I also know about the 3 provided caseless models as talked about [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html).  But what if I want to train my own caseless model, what is the trick there?  I have a bunch of all uppercase documents for training.  Do I use the same training process or are there special/different features for the caseless models or are there properties that need to be set?  I can't find a description as to how the provided caseless models were created.

Comment: By the way, I would love if dynamically ner classification could detect whether documents or sentences were caseless  or mixed case and we could switch to the appropriate model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one property change in our models, which is that you want to have it invoke a function that removes case information before words are processed for classification. We do that with this property value (which also maps some words to American spelling):

`wordFunction = edu.stanford.nlp.process.LowercaseAndAmericanizeFunction`

but there is also simply:

`wordFunction = edu.stanford.nlp.process.LowercaseFunction`

Having more automatic stuff for deciding document format (hard/soft line breaks), case, or even language would be nice, but at present we don't have any of those....